# Solution of an integral equation 3

Tags: integration

There is an integral equation and i even don't know with what to start because there they were readily introduced in an exercise in a Calculus book without describing how to solve them. I just know as much that it is a Volterra equation of $2^{nd}$ kind. Please show how to solve it. The equation is:

$$y(x) = 2 + \int_{2}^x t - ty(t)\, dt$$

Comment: In a calculus book, eh?  What do you get when you differentiate that equation?

Comment: @GEdgar with respect to what?

Comment: $y'(x) = \cdots$

Comment: dy(x)/dx = d/dx(integral from 2 to x of [t - ty(t)]dt)

Comment: Take a look at this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign link.

Comment: @chinny84 The derivative of the integral is x - xy(x). Thanks for adding to my knowledge. The final answer becomes 1 + e^2-x^2/2.

Comment: No worries. That method in my link is a very powerful technique and sits well in anyone's "mathematical toolbox" :).

Answer (score 2):

You'll differentiaite with respect to $x$ to get:

$$
y'(x) = x-xy(x)\\
\frac{dy(x)}{dx} = x(1-y(x))\\
\frac{dy(x)}{1-y(x)} = x dx\\
\int \frac{dy(x)}{1-y(x)} = \int x dx\\
-ln|1-y(x)| = x^2/2+C
$$

Note that for $x=2$:

$$
y(2) = 2+\int_{2}^{2}t-ty(t) dt = 2
$$

So to get $C$, just put $x=2$ and you'll get:

$$
C = -2
$$

$$
-ln|1-y(x)| = x^2/2-2\\
ln|1-y(x)| = 2-x^2/2\\
|1-y(x)| = {e}^{2-x^2/2}\\
1-y(x) = \pm {e}^{2-x^2/2}\\
y(x) = 1\pm {e}^{2-x^2/2}
$$

But since $y(2)=2$ we keep $+$ sign to get:

$$
y(x) = 1+{e}^{2-x^2/2}
$$

Comment: The answer is 1 + exp(2-x^2/2)

Comment: yes I edited that

Comment: Sometimes I make stupid careless mistakes ^^